# In which late-stage Grand Slam tennis matches has a single player won 200+ points?

Tags: trivia, tennis, statistics

Which Grand Slam matches, in the Round of 16 or later, have had 200 or more points won by a single player?

Two known examples are

- Djokovic v. Wawrinka at Australian Open 2013: 209-200
- Federer v. Roddick at Wimbledon 2009: 223-213